# Data validate in Struts 2 + Annotiation + Model driven

Tags: java, validation

I want to impliment data validation using Struts 2 Annotation.

**My project struct:**

[image]

In Customer Model class I try to use: @RequiredStringValidator, but it's fail.
**My Model class**

```
package com.dieu.customer.model;

import java.util.Date;


import javax.persistence.*;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.RequiredStringValidator;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.ValidatorType;

@Entity
@Table(name="test.customer")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long customerId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Date createdDate;   

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name, String ADDRESS, Date CREATED_DATE) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = ADDRESS;
        this.createdDate = CREATED_DATE;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Long CUSTOMER_ID) {
        this.customerId = CUSTOMER_ID;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @RequiredStringValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message = "The name is required.")
    public void setName(String NAME) {
        this.name = NAME;
    }

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    @RequiredStringValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, message = "The name is required.")
    public void setAddress(String ADDRESS) {
        this.address = ADDRESS;
    }

    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date CREATED_DATE) {
        this.createdDate = CREATED_DATE;
    }

}
```

In CustomerAction class, I've try to use @RequiredFieldValidator in Customer Add Action, but it fail too.

**My Action class**

```
package com.dieu.customer.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.dieu.customer.bo.CustomerBo;
import com.dieu.customer.model.Customer;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.RequiredFieldValidator;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.RequiredStringValidator;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.ValidatorType;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.VisitorFieldValidator;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@Namespace(value = "/")
public class CustomerAction implements ModelDriven{

    Customer customer = new Customer(); 
    List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();    
    CustomerBo customerBo;


    Customer editCustomer = new Customer(); 
    public void setEditCustomer(Customer editCustomer) {
        this.editCustomer = editCustomer;
    }

    public Customer getEditCustomer(){
        return this.editCustomer;
    }

    //DI via Spring
    public void setCustomerBo(CustomerBo customerBo) {
        this.customerBo = customerBo;
    }

    public Object getModel() {
        return customer;
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
    }

    //save customer 
    @Action(value = "/addCustomerAction", results = {@Result(name = "success", type="redirectAction", location = "listCustomerAction")})
    @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE,
                            message = "Please specify your current job.",
                            fieldName = "name")
    public String addCustomer() throws Exception{

        //save it
        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        customerBo.addCustomer(customer);

        return "success";

    }

    //list all customers
    @Action(value = "/listCustomerAction", results = {@Result(name = "success", location = "/pages/customer.jsp")})
    public String listCustomer() throws Exception{

        customerList = customerBo.listCustomer();       
        return "success";

    }


    @Action(value = "/deleteCustomerAction", results = {@Result(name = "success", type="redirectAction", location = "listCustomerAction")})                                                                 
    public String deleteCustomer() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

        customerBo.deleteCustomer(Long.parseLong( request.getParameter("customerId")));

        return "success";

    }

    @Action(value = "/getCustomerAction", results = {@Result(name = "success", location = "/pages/edit.jsp")})
    public String editCustomer() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

        editCustomer = customerBo.findCustomer(Long.parseLong( request.getParameter("customerId")));    

        return "success";

    }

    @Action(value = "/updateCustomerAction", results = {@Result(name = "success", type="redirectAction", location = "listCustomerAction")})                     
    public String updateCustomer() throws Exception{

        //save it
        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        customerBo.addCustomer(customer);

        return "success";

    }

}
```

**My JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<h2>Add Customer</h2>
<s:form action="addCustomerAction" >
  <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" />
  <s:textarea name="address" label="Address" cols="50" rows="5" />
  <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

**My web UI and Customer List**

[image]

Can someone help me to validate input data using Struts 2 Annotion.

Comment: Does the  addCustomer() get invoked when you submit the form ?
if yes , Should not you add <s:fielderror />  in the <s:form> ?

Comment: Yes, addCustomer() can work correctly , but it's accept Null value too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052157/how-to-implement-validations-using-annotations-in-struts2-in-action-that-impleme

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper: I've follow your link.
extends CustomerActin to ActionSupport, and add setter, getter method.

`public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Customer>{`

And add `@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)` for getter medthod. Error 404 occurred: HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.dieu.customer.action.CustomerAction and result input

Comment: Well, now it means that the validation is now happening, but it could not find the input page. Meaning you have the success page defined as results = {@Result(name = "success", type="redirectAction", location = "listCustomerAction")}, but no name="input" , that is why it fails, add something like   @Result(name = "input", type = "<YOURTYPEHERE>"), don't use redirectAction though.

Comment: No, 404 error while i'm try to load listCustomerAction. Still not submit AddCustomerAction yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90011/discussion-between-the-neo-noir-developer-and-dieu-luong).